# Is it possible to have complexType and elements inside but without the sequence part

Tags: xml, sequence

I hava a xml doc (and complex element) that is similar to this example:

```
<xs:element name="employee">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But in my xml it shouldn't matter if I add firstname or lastname first. 
So I would like to remove the "xs:sequence" part but I am not sure what I should replace it with.

If it is not possible - then why is it not possible?

**Update:** 
If I change it with < cx:all> I get this error: "The {max occurs} of all the {parties} of an all group must be 0 or 1".

Comment: yes, that's a known system limitation of <xs:all> - maxOccurs can be only 0 or 1. You didn't mention anything else in your example, either.....

Comment: Is there any other option than <xs: all> where I don't get this limitation?

Comment: An employee can have more than one first name or more than one last name?

Comment: No, `<xs:all>` is your only other choice besides the sequence, I'm afraid, sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `<xs:all>` instead of `<xs:sequence>`:

```
<xs:element name="employee">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:all>
   <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:all>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

See the [W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp) on the schema indicators:

> All Indicator
>
> The `<all>` indicator specifies that the
>   child elements can appear in any
>   order, and that each child element
>   must occur only once:

Comment: If I change it with < cx:all> I get this error: "The {max occurs} of all the {parties} of an all group must be 0 or 1".

Comment: yes, that's a limitation of `<xs:all>` - maxOccurs can be only 0 or 1. You didn't mention anything else in your example, either.....

Answer (score 2):

```
<xs:element name="employee">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:choice>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This will allow you to have elements in any sequence and quantity.

Comment: Unfortunately, not true. `<xs:choice>` only allows one of the specified elements. So in your example it would only allow firstname *XOR* lastname (but could then contain any number of occurrences that element).

Answer (score 0):

You want the [All indicator](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_all.asp) (`<xs:all>`).

```
<xs:element name="employee">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:all>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The [XML Schema Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/) on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is very helpful.

Comment: If I change it with < cx:all> I get this error: "The {max occurs} of all the {parties} of an all group must be 0 or 1".